# Where is not or where is different in laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi my query checks if a field is not empty or the data is validated:

```
return $this->with(array('funcionario', 'item_contabil'))
        ->where('tb_horario.cod_funcionario', $codfunc)
        ->whereBetween('tb_horario.data', array($datainicio, $datafinal))
        ->where('tb_horario.validado', 0)
        ->where('tb_horario.motivo','<>', '')
        ->orderBy('tb_horario.data')
        ->count();
```

I want to know if in this line i can use something like whereNot() or whereDifferent() in laravel 4:

```
->where('tb_horario.motivo','<>', '')
```

Exists something like that???
thxx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot of things with Laravel Query Builder:

Copied from the [Docs(Advanced Wheres)](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres):

```
->where('tb_horario.cod_funcionario', '=', 'John')
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
                $query->where('tb_horario.validado', '>', 100)
                      ->where('tb_horario.motivo', '<>', '');
            })->get();
```

Or something like this

```
 ->where('tb_horario.cod_funcionario', '=', 'John')
            ->whereRaw('tb_horario.validado > 100');
            ->get();
```

Laravel offers several options to create queries...

```
whereNotIn
whereNotExists
whereExists
...
```

Have a look at the [API-Docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/). I'm sure you'll find something, which suits you.